# created an app called users ,want to use "from users import views as v" .Already made changes in settings.py file. But it says unreferenced error?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

[image]

```
from users import views is not working
```

I created two apps. the first one works fine. The same way I created another app called as users. But when I import it, it says unreferenced error. I already added it in installed apps in the main settings.py file of the project.

There are two apps. The first one is working fine. The second one is giving error when I import it. It says unreferenced error

[image]

Comment: Have you registered the second app in **installed apps** in your settings.py?

Comment: Please update your question with an example of your error (not as a picture...). The error in the picture you posted does not match your code, you no longer have `view_users` in a url pattern

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` in your `users` folder? Why would you be importing `views` from `models`?

Answer (score 0):

Change url :
add `urls.py` in users.
and add this line:

```
from user import views as v_register
```

and add this line in blog url.

```
path('users/', include(users.urls)),
```

Comment: No not working, I don't know why it does not recognize the user app itself